# How to make legend's line wider in a react-vis XYPlot

Tags: clojurescript, react-vis

The `DiscreteColorLegend`s of an `XYPlot` are a little narrow for me:

[image: Solid lines graph]

Specially when I want to make them other than solid:

[image: Dashed lines graph]

I browsed the documentation, and even the source code; I think that the length is determined in line 59 of this file: https://github.com/uber/react-vis/blob/master/packages/react-vis/src/legends/discrete-color-legend-item.js :

```
d="M 0, 1 L 14, 1"
```

Can I change it in my own local source code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a 'semi' solution. I'm not proud of it, but maybe can help others. I did two things:

1. After compiling (with `clojure -A:fig:min`), I changed the string cited above using `sed` (28 doubled the size of the legend):

`sed -i 's/"M 0, 1 L 14, 1"/"M 0, 1 L 28, 1"/' dev-main.js`

2. Then, in the file `legends.css`, I changed this:

```
.rv-discrete-color-legend-item__title {
  margin-left: 10px;
}
```

into this:

```
.rv-discrete-color-legend-item__title {
  margin-left: 20px;
}
```

Now, al least, it looks better:

[image]